# Сложность с запятой

Tags: пунктуация

**Мы идём куда-то. А куда(,) мы не знаем.**

Как по мне, тут не нужна запятая, но здесь всё-таки присутствует интонация, которая может запутать. Нужна ли здесь запятая или не нужна?

Answer (score 2):

В подобных случаях ставится тире.

Тире ставится для интонационного отделения главной части сложноподчиненного предложения от придаточной. Чаще всего тире употребляется в тех случаях, когда главной части предшествует:

1) придаточная изъяснительная: Как он добрался сюда — уж этого никак не мог он понять (Г.); Как рассказывал учитель — долго слушал у окна я (Пл.); Конечно, хорошо, что он с ней венчается, а как жить будут — кто знает (М. Г.); За что он её мучил — она так и не спросила; **Он придёт, но когда — не знаю (ср. при другом порядке частей: Не знаю, когда он придёт); Они уехали, но куда — не сказали;**

[См.: Справочник по русскому языку: орфография и пунктуация](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=142#pp142)

Comment: Если в данном случае не поставить тире, это будет ошибкой?

Comment: В правилах пунктуации о запятой в этом случае ничего говорится.

Comment: Это будет ошибкой, если я не поставлю ни тире, ни запятую?

Comment: Это СПП. Знак препинания (тире) здесь обязателен. Отсутсвие тире - пунктуационная ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

Розенталь: **При интонационном подчеркивании** придаточные изъяснительные, реже условные и уступительные, стоящие впереди главного предложения, **могут отделяться** от него не запятой, а тире.

В данном случае возможны оба варианта, авторский выбор:

(1) Мы идём куда-то. А куда, мы не знаем.

(2) Мы идём куда-то. А кудА — мы не знаем. (Пауза и тире, логическое выделение местоимения КУДА).

Сравнить: **Мы идём куда-то, а куда — не знаем**. При такой структуре (пропущенное подлежащее) тире обычно ставится.

**Примеры:**

Я сказал: ― **А куда, неизвестно**?  [Виктор Драгунский. Денискины рассказы/ Девочка на шаре (1963)]

Дениска пожал плечами. ― Ездили куда-то, **а куда, не знаю**. Батя не дюже любит о своих делах разговаривать. [Г. М. Марков. Строговы. Кн. 2 (1936-1948)]

― Послезавтра с вещами, а **куда ― не знаю.** [Вацлав Михальский. Одинокому везде пустыня (2003)]

«Конь несет меня лихой, **а куда – не знаю»**. [В. П. Катаев. Юношеский роман (1980-1981)]

Comment: А насколько запятая оправдана здесь? В вариативных знаках препинания у Розенталя об этом ничего не говорится.

Comment: http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/49.htm#з_05 Розенталь говорит, что МОЖНО ставить тире (а не запятую)  при интонационном подчеркивании. Обычно тире ставится, если предложения неполные и тире необходимо  для понимания структуры СПП. Здесь такой необходимости нет, поэтому автор решает, стоит ли ему выделять логическим ударением  слово КУДА.

Comment: Предложение как раз неполное. А куда (идем) - мы не знаем. Поэтому тире здесь уместнее.

Comment: Минус - не мой.

Comment: Серж, я имею в  виду: мы не знаем, а это полное предложение. Если убрать "мы", то тогда надо ставить тире.

Comment: Вы не помните, есть у Розенталя такое правило: В условиях контекста возможна постановка запятой и перед одиночным союзным словом: Что же надо делать? Научите,  что (усиленное логическое выделение местоимения). подчеркивает значение местоимения и оправдывается вопросительной интонацией)https://orfogrammka.ru/

Comment: Да, но здесь запятая стоит пред союзом, а в нашем примере после.

Comment: В том-то и дело: Розенталь говорит можно. примеры тоже есть. А правилах - не сказано ничего.

Comment: У нас -  да, это немного другая тема.  Я просто не могу найти правило в классической записи, чтобы можно было на него сослаться.  Постановка запятой в некоторых случаях допускается, то есть правило об отсутствии запятой  не абсолютного действия.

Comment: Да, я том же говорю. Классической записи нет, а примеры есть. Я поэтому в ответе написал,что в правилах пунктуации о запятой в этом случае ничего говорится.

Comment: Серж, я нашла правило у Розенталя на тему  "идем не знаю куда".  Одиночное местоимение в особых случаях может отделяться запятой. "Если при союзном слове имеется частица, то постановка запятой факультативна; ср.: Я не помню, что именно; Он затрудняется сказать, что ещё; 
В условиях контекста возможна постановка запятой и перед одиночным союзным словом; ср.: Что же надо делать? Научите, что". https://profilib.com/chtenie/27738/ditmar-rozental-spravochnik-po-russkomu-yazyku-punktuatsiya-42.php

Comment: Так ведь придаточное стоит после главного. Запятая стоит пред союзом, а в нашем примере после.

Comment: Да я не про наш пример говорю, просто  не должно быть категоричности утверждений на любую тему.  Например: одиночное местоимение запятой не отделяется. Но это основное правило, но есть исключения. Каждый случай  решается индивидуально, а не подгоняется под единое правило. А  в нашем случае тире интонационное, и  оно факультативно по своей природе. Надо понять, почему оно ставится, и тогда будет ясно, когда его можно не ставить.

Comment: Я тоже говорю об этом. У Розенталя не категорично говорится о тире. Просто в разделе "Вариативные знаки препинания" тоже ничего не говорится.

Comment: Тем более на практике встречается запятая.

Answer (score 0):

**Запятая не нужна**, её использование будет ошибкой, поскольку "куда" не здесь имеет зависимых слов и является не союзным словом, а обычным членом предложения.

Насчет тире. Да, тире здесь вполне можно рекомендовать, но оно не решает проблему в целом и не раскрывает сути пунктуационного правила ибо изменение порядка слов приводит к к форме, где тире исключено. ***"[идем,] не знаем куда.***  Здесь-то вы запятую перед "куда" не поставите?! Исходная форма грамматически ничем не отличается.